# How to check if a kendo grid contains specific item with javascript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, grid

I have an ASP.NET MVC project. In one view there is a Kendo Grid named `FullNameList` and there is only one column named `FullName`, there is bunch of data inside the grid; all of them are simple string names. I want to know if there is a **method** to check whether the kendo grid contains an *specific item* or not? If not how can I iterate through datasource items to check one by one the items?

Comment: i must add that i have read bunch of questions related to kendo grid to find the answer with similar or a little  different question but i couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the client (i.e. browser) the data source data can be searched using javascript Array `some` method:

```
var searchName = "Yekanchi";

var searchNameFound = $("#FullNameList").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().some(
  function (dataItem) {
    return dataItem.FullName == searchName;        
  });
```

[Some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/some)

> The **`some()`** method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

Comment: The OP wants to know only if the item is there or not so it's better to use `some` instead of `filter`.